# Resize Fragment size in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to obtain somthing like that

[image: aim]

but ive obtain this

[image: :(]  .

`Fragment` takes all the screen. How can i set it up for example for 500dpi height and for the list layout for the rest screen.

Question 2. Is there any posibility to ad show/hide `Button`, that will resize the `Fragment` (on show the item the `Fragment` height incresed and hide the list)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.k.guides4art20.MainActivity"
>
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip" >


        <EditText
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="szukaj"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filters"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="filtry"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
         >

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name = "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.k.guides4art20.MapsActivity"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_span="2" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2">

        </ListView>
        </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Your fragment with map fill your layout, what you want to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert fragment into layout and set `layout_height`

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.k.guides4art20.MainActivity"
    android:id="@id/main"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchBarLay">
        <EditText
            android:hint="szukaj"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filters"
            android:text="filtry"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:autoText="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:id="@+id/mapLay"
        android:background="@color/blue25">
        <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            tools:context="com.example.k.guides4art20.MapsActivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listLay">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Question 2 Yes, You can do this. By changing param Visibility.

```
layMap.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
layList.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
```

Comment: I tried your way and fragment is setting up correcly now but still doesnt display the list part

Answer (score 0):

Take Linear layout as parent and divide the screen in portions using weight attribute. In one take one fragment and on other side take map fragment. This will solve your problem. Otherwise the map will occupy whole screen.
Or you can move for navigation slide drawer keep it fixed open for large size devices ad for small keep it in hide manner and control it with hamburger icon.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` as container of your elements instead of `TableLayout`, then in your fragment set

```
android:layout_height="500dp"
```